# Ruby on Rails project structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, structure

I am studying Ruby on Rails for several weeks now, following some tutorials and little articles. Could you recommend some article or video tutorial with a good high level overview of the project structure, which  also covers how things get connected (models, views, controllers, assets and so on) between each other to form a web app?
   I think I got to deep into details not understanding the basics.

Comment: I recommend http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book for beginners

Comment: Please read [stackoverflow faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: try these simple link...
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-directory-structure.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 30.000 feet overview is that Rails is a lot like Magic :)

There are a lot of conventions around you should know, but they are all pretty self-explanatory and simple.

First off: You don't need to connect anything in a Rails application - Rails does that for you through the conventions.

So first for the folder structure.

Your app lives in the `/app` directory and the config in `/config`. Database files and migrations inside `/db` etc.. `/public` is where all the stuff that's not managed by rails goes (`robots.txt` , static content etc).

inside `/app` you will typically have:

```
app
 - assets
 - controllers
 - models
 - views
```

**Assets** is where your JavaScript, CSS and Image files for the app go.

**Controllers** is where you put your controllers.
The convention here is as follows:

`ApplicationController` is derived from `ActionController::Base` and is intended as the base class for all your application's controllers. The controller is instantly loaded when it's name matches it's class name.
So `ApplicationController` is expected to be declared inside `application_controller.rb`.
Another sample would be a `PostsController` that goes into the `posts_controller.rb` file.

The convention here is also that controllers that manage many things (posts, clients, links..) are plural whereas singular resources like profile, account are singular - but that's no real hard rule.

**Models** is where the ActiveRecord models go, they are defined as simple classes extending `ActiveRecord::Base` and go into the same file as their class name: `Post` goes into `post.rb`, `User` goes into `user.rb`.

**Views** is a bit special as it contains sub-folders on a per-controller basis.
So if you have a `PostsController` and a `CommentsController` you'll have two folders inside `/views`: `posts` and `comments`.

Inside these view folders you'll put files that correspond to the actions (methods) inside the controller. So typically you'll have a `index.html.erb` file that will be rendered when the `index` method on the controller gets called.

As you can see this is where the magic happens, you just have to name stuff the right way and Rails figures out things on it's own. The only special case where you have to explicitly do something to make it work is the routing.

**Routing** goes into `/config/routes.rb` and this file is used to tell the Rails application what urls map to what actions in your controllers. But I suggest you look that up in the Rails guides or in the numerous tutorials others have posted in this question.

Comment: Bad thing that magic is something people can't explain =) Good overview of the project structure, thanks. I guess just need practice to understand how things are done in RoR if its magic?!)

Answer (score 3):

Three things:

- Start off with the [Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)
- Move into [Michael Hartl's tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/)
- Enjoy some [Railscasts](http://www.railscasts.com)

The order is important!

Goodluck!

Comment: missed out the first)

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to rails then you should follow this basic tutorial.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this resource, I found it useful.

http://www.codethinked.com/rails-3-baby-steps-series